# Can not Fetch Data with JPQL using Postgres Database Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc, jpql

I am trying to develop SpringMVC framework, everything working fine but when I run my codes, data are not fetched from Postgres database using JPQL.

***domain model class***

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Version;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Contact")
    @NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name="Contact.findAll", query="select c from Contact c")
    })

    public class Contact implements Serializable {

        private Long id;
        private int version;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String description;
getter and setter defined
```

***Repository Class***

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.apress.prospring3.ch17.domain.Contact;
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ContactRepository implements CrudRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        List<Contact> contact = manager.createNamedQuery("Contact.findAll", 
                Contact.class).getResultList();
        return contact;
    }
}
```

***Controller Class***

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.apress.prospring3.ch17.domain.Contact;
import com.apress.prospring3.ch17.service.ContactService;

@RequestMapping("/contact")
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @Autowired
    ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model uiModel) {
        List<Contact> contacts = contactService.findAll();
        uiModel.addAttribute("contacts", contacts);
        return "contacts/list";

    }
}
```

***Front View (list.jspx)***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:joda="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    <h1>Contact Listing</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Birth Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${contacts}" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${contact.firstName}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

***Server Logs***

> Hibernate: select contact0_.ID as ID1_0_, contact0_.DESCRIPTION as
>   DESCRIPT2_0_, contact0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST_NA3_0_,
>   contact0_.LAST_NAME as LAST_NAM4_0_, contact0_.VERSION as VERSION5_0_
>   from Contact contact0_
>
> Jan 24, 2016 2:19:14 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache
>   tldScanJar INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained
>   no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of
>   JARs that were scanned where no TLDs were found. Skipping JAR scanning
>   can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

***Output***

[image]

***Postgres DataBase data***
[image]

**Please correct me what I am missing.
Thank you so much.**

Comment: Did the commit the transaction in posgres DB after inserting the data? Also try sysout of contact list in the controller and see if that is having any data?

Comment: The query is executed, as the logs show. Use your debugger, or even simple System.out.println() calls in the repository, service, controller, etc. to see what the returned list contains at each level.

Comment: Hi All, I have tried all your advices but can't able to fetch data. Please find below answer. Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized what I have missed.

I forget to declare empty constructor for my model class.

```
public class Contact implements Serializable {

        private Long id;
        private int version;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String description;
public Contact(){} // This invoke to model with Entity class and interact with Database
getter and setter defined
```